# Mysql composite indexing with tenant_id

Tags: mysql, indexing, multi-tenant

We have a multitenant application that has a table with 129 fields that can all be used in WHERE and ORDER BY clauses. I spent 5 days now trying to find out the best indexing strategy for us, I gained lot of knowledge but I still have some questions.

1) When creating an index should I always make it a composite index with tenant_id in the first place ?(all queries have tenant_id = ? in there WHERE clause)

2) Since all the columns can be used in both the WHERE clause and the order by clause, should I create an index on them all ? (right know when I order by a column that has no index it takes 6s to execute with a tenant that has about 1,500,000 rows )

3) make the PK (tenant_id, ID), but wouldn't this affect the joins to that table ?

Any advice on how to handle this would be much appreciated.

======
The database engine is InnoDB

=======

structure :

```
ID bigint(20) auto_increment primary
tenant_id int(11)
created_by int(11)
created_on Timestamp
updated_by int(11)
updated_on Timestamp
owner_id int(11)
first_name VARCHAR(60)
last_name VARCHAR(60)
.
.
.
(some 120 other columns that are all searchable)
```

Comment: Without knowing the table structure, it's hard to advise on this issue.

Comment: ok I'll post the structure

Comment: What is the table engine? If this is InnoDB, make sure you have innodb_buffer_pool_size as larger as you can. If you make the PK tenant_id + some unique id (do you have another unique constrain other than ID), then it will be part of any index and you don't need to have it in other indexes, also, since the data will be clustered by tenant_id range queries will be faster. Additionally, you can partition the table by tenant_id

Comment: yes it is InnoDB, if I make the PK tenant_id + some unique id would it not affect the joins that use the ID column ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few brief answers to the questions. As far as I can see you are confused with using `indexes`

Consider creating Indexes on columns if the Ratio -

`Consideration 1` -

> (Number of UNIQUE Entries of the Columns)/(Number of Total Entries in the Column) ~= 1

That is Count of DISTINCT rows in a particular column is high.

Creating an **extra** `index` will always create overhead for the MySQL server, so you **MUST NOT** create every column an `index`. *There is also a limit on number of indexes your single table can have =  64 per table*

Now if your `tenant_id` is present in all the search queries, you should consider it as an `index` or in a `composite key`,

provided that -

`Consideration 2` - number of `UPDATEs` are less that number of `SELECTs` on the `tenant_id`

`Consideration 3` - The `indexe`s should be as small as possible in terms of `data types`. You **MUST NOT** create a `varchar 64` an index 
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/08/16/mysql-indexing-best-practices-webinar-questions-followup/

`Point to Note 1` - Even if you do declare any column an index, MySQL optimizer may still not consider it as best plan of query execution. So always use `EXPLAIN` to know whats going on. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/

`Point to Note 2` - 
You may want to `cache` your search queries, so remember not to use unpredicted statements in your `SELECT` queries, such as `NOW()`

Lastly - making the PK (tenant_id, ID) should not affect the joins on your table. 
And an awesome link to answer all your questions in general - http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/WEBINAR-MySQL-Indexing-Best-Practices.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot. So should I use PK (tenant_id, ID) or just include the tenant_id in every index (ALL queries include where tenant_id=?)

Comment: Primary key's role is to find out a unique row, and since that's auto inc in your table, you can keep the single primary key and add `tenant_id` as an seperate index. No issues there.

Comment: @redmoon7777 - i could have put in more details, but that would have made this answer too long to read. Anyways you can check for the webinar recording on the same topic too. http://www.percona.com/webinars/2012-08-15-mysql-indexing-best-practices