# How to optimise below sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

What I'm doing here is getting the reservations and the user which are duplicate. Here reservation ticket can not be printed twice. If a user prints a ticket tracker table updates with that record. If a user prints the same ticket twice it's marked as a duplicate. What subquery does here is return some reservation ids which are marked as duplicates.

```
    SELECT t1.id AS res_id,
       t1.tx_id,
       t1.tx_date,
       t1.bx_date,
       t1.method,
       t1.theater_id,
       t1.showtime_id,
       t1.category_id,
       t1.amount,
       t1.fname,
       t1.status,
       t1.mobile,
       u.username,
       t2.*
FROM `reservation` AS t1
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT *
   FROM `tracker`
   WHERE reservation_id IN
       ( SELECT reservation_id
        FROM `tracker`
        GROUP BY reservation_id HAVING ( METHOD = 1
                                        AND TYPE = 0
                                        AND COUNT(*) > 1 )
        OR ( METHOD = 1
            AND TYPE = 1
            AND COUNT(*) > 1 )
        OR ( METHOD = 2
            AND TYPE = 2
            AND COUNT(*) > 0 )
        OR ( METHOD = 3
            AND TYPE = 0
            AND COUNT(*) > 0 )
        OR ( METHOD = 3
            AND TYPE = 1
            AND COUNT(*) > 1 )
        OR ( METHOD = 3
            AND TYPE = 3
            AND COUNT(*) > 0 )) ) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.reservation_id
INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON u.id = t2.user_id
WHERE t2.resolved = 0
  AND t2.duplicate = 1
ORDER BY t2.issue_date DESC, t1.id DESC
```

EXPLAIN Command of the above query.

[image]

What should I do? If I'm index which keys should I use? How can I decide which keys to index? I know subquery slows me down What procedures should I follow to eliminate the slowness?

Comment: please paste your explain plan

Comment: what do you mean by explain plan?

Comment: Explain ::  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html

Comment: I have posted a screenshot in the question

Comment: Check this post if you want to know about key optimization - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064489/mysql-composite-indexing-with-tenant-id/14088424#14088424

Comment: Check this post if you need to know about FORCE INDEX - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137549/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-mysql-explain/14137997#14137997

Comment: The `GROUP BY reservation_id HAVING ...` part seems fishy. Is `reservation_id` the primary key of `tracker`? If not, the `HAVING method=1 AND type=0` will choose arbitrary values for these columns because they are not included in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @ypercube  ... and if `reservation_id` _is_ the primary key, no `reservation_id` will be found where `COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: Then your query is broken. Describe what you want to achieve, give table with sample data, so someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, `exists` subqueries are often faster than `in` subqueries.  You might try:

```
SELECT t1.id AS res_id, t1.tx_id, t1.tx_date, t1.bx_date,t1.method, t1.theater_id, t1.showtime_id,
       t1.category_id, t1.amount, t1.fname, t1.status, t1.mobile, u.username, t2.*
FROM `reservation` t1 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT *
      FROM `tracker` t
      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM `tracker` t3
                    where t3.reservation_id = t.reservation_id
                    GROUP BY reservation_id
                    HAVING (METHOD = 1 AND TYPE = 0 AND COUNT(*) > 1) OR
                           (METHOD = 1 AND TYPE = 1 AND COUNT(*) > 1) OR
                           (METHOD = 2 AND TYPE = 2 AND COUNT(*) > 0) OR
                           (METHOD = 3 AND TYPE = 0 AND COUNT(*) > 0) OR
                           (METHOD = 3 AND TYPE = 1 AND COUNT(*) > 1) OR
                           (METHOD = 3 AND TYPE = 3 AND COUNT(*) > 0)
                   )
     ) t2
     ON t1.id = t2.reservation_id INNER JOIN
     `users` AS u ON u.id = t2.user_id
WHERE t2.resolved = 0 AND t2.duplicate = 1
ORDER BY t2.issue_date DESC, t1.id DESC
```

I notice the subquery is using Hidden Columns in the `having` clause.  It may not be doing what you expect.  Normally, the query would include `method` and `type` in the `group by` clause or have an expression such as `max(Method)`.

Comment: super duper awesome optimisation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if you can please explain what have you done in the subquery. I would really love to learn.

Comment: I simply replaced the construct `in (subquery)` with `exists (select 1 from (subquery with correlated where clause)`.  This is a hack because MySQL sometimes does not optimize `in` as efficiently as the exists.